# How can I create SparseArray by imposing conditions?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I have two lists: one for directed links `list1` and another `list2` for the values associated with the links.

```
list1 = {{1 \[DirectedEdge] 4}, {3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge]
3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4}};

list2 = {{0.1}, {0.4, 0.7, 0.9}};
```

I want to create two `SparseArray`s of size `(10,10)`. One for a single link,

```
{1 \[DirectedEdge] 4}
```

with the associated value of `0.1`. Another `SparseArray` of the same size for three links:

```
{3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge]3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4}
```

with the associated values in

```
{0.4, 0.7, 0.9}.
```

Comment: Did you want something like `PadRight[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[Graph[{3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4}, EdgeWeight -> {0.4, 0.7, 0.9}]], {10, 10}]`?

Comment: @J.M. will be back soon: Not quite. `EdgeWeights` are misplaced. `DirectedGraph` has links following matrix index (row->column). In your answer, the placement of weights is not what I wanted.

Comment: OK, then does `PadRight[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Range[3], {3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4}, EdgeWeight -> {0.4, 0.7, 0.9}]], {10, 10}]` do what you want?

Comment: @J.M. will be back soon: Now it works fine. In my example, I had two separate directed graphs with specific edge weights. Would it be possible for doing the same operation for two graphs automatically because I have a large number of graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MapThread[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Range@10, #, EdgeWeight -> #2]] &, {list1, list2}]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm[Row[MatrixForm /@ %]]
```

> $\small\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

You can also use

```
SparseArray[#, {10, 10}] & /@ (Rule @@@ Transpose[{list1 /. DirectedEdge -> List, list2}])
```